# How to optimize MySQL subqueries when joining multiple views?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

Assume I have the following 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `tablea` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nameA` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tableb` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idA` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nameB` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idA` (`idA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I want to join these 2 tables efficiently I can run this query

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 20
```

Lets say that I can't use `INNER JOIN` like the example above rather I have to use a sub query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM tableB
) AS b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 20;
```

Since the sub query is a derived query, MySQL will pulls **all** the records from `tableB`, then it pulls 1 record from `tableA` "`WHERE id = 20`", and finally it joins the 2 data sets together.

If the second query is written like that I can tune it like this "assume I can't use the syntax is query 1 above"

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM tableB
    WHERE id = 20
) AS b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 20;
```

The problem that I am trying to explain here is this; Assume `tableA` and `tableB` are a view not tables, each view with a complex query "many joins."
 And, I want to join the two views together `ON a.id = b.ida`. I won't be able to add the `WHERE id = 20` clause to the sub query sine MySQL does not support sub quires "each query will have to be a single view."

```
CREATE VIEW viewA AS SELECT * FROM tableA;
CREATE VIEW viewB AS SELECT * FROM tableB;
CREATE VIEW viewAll AS
```

SELECT b.*
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON b.ida = a.id

```
SELECT * FROM viewAll WHERE id = 20;
```

How can I optimize this query when using views?

I need to tell MySQL to only pull the records where the `id = 20` which is set by the `ON` clause.

here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f24d/2) that has the tables/views and some sample data
your help is appreciated it.

Comment: You want to use `algorithm = MERGE` when you define the view.  If you can, then MySQL might be more reasonable in the optimization.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried that on the sub quires but that did not help. should all the views involve have a merge algorithm or just the sub quires?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  that did not do much on improvement. any other suggestion?

Comment: . . You won't like the answer.  MySQL really cannot optimize views very well, so don't use them.

Comment: I try not to use them, but the problem is that I have a system that generate custom attributes so I am hoping for one pivot view where I can easily access the custom attributes This is where I need a view otherwise it will be insane to query the custom attributes every time.